# 404 error - Google attempting to index ColdFusion CFC

Tags: iis, coldfusion, http-status-code-404, cfc, googlebot

For months, our IIS/ColdFusion server has been throwing 404 errors during Google crawler scans.  Normally it's easy to track these down but in this case, Google is trying to scan our CFC files.  The files do exist, but they are not exposed to the Internet - only to the ColdFusion server.  Nevertheless, Google is seeing links to the CFCs somewhere on our site and is trying to follow them.

Below is a dump of our CGI structure during one of the 404's.  `baseCFC` is a CF Mapping to `D:\Domains\[domain]\cfc`.  All references to `baseCFC` in our source code are either in a `<cfajaxproxy>` tag, or a `CreateObject()` call in Application.CFC (examples below).

Perhaps this is an important clue: `baseCFC` refers to `D:\Domains\[domain]\cfc`, but Google is trying to reach `D:\Domains\[domain]\www\baseCFC`, which is our site's home directory.  Apparently Google sees `baseCFC` as a normal (unmapped) directory on the server and wants to scan it.

[image]

Here are examples of the two types of `baseCFC` references in our code:

<cfajaxproxy>:

```
<cfajaxproxy cfc="baseCFC.Misc" jsclassname="ajxMisc">
```

CreateObject():

```
<cfscript>
  request.Misc = CreateObject( "component", "baseCFC.Misc" );
</cfscript>
```

How do we troubleshoot these CFC-related 404 errors?  Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The javascript created by `cfajaxproxy` includes the location of the cfc.  Viewing the source of your page you should be able to find the string `'/baseCFC/Statement.cfc'`.  That is how Google is finding them.

A quick way to get Google to ignore them is to modify your `robots.txt` file to exclude the `baseCFC` "directory".

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /baseCFC/
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense!  We should know within 24 hours if it helped; if it does I'll accept this answer.  Thanks so much.